# Rails autoloading example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

I am newbie to Ruby on Rails and I broken my head at Rails autoloading mechanisms.

I have code like that in my `/app/helpers/posts_helper.rb` :

```
module PostsHelper  
  def markdown_render(data)
    Utils::Markdown.render data
  end
end
```

And I have `/app/utils/markdown.rb` with something like:

```
module Utils
  class Markdown
    class << self
      def render(data)
        # render some dataz
      end
    end
  end
end
```

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html, `Utils::Markdown` will be loaded from `/app/utils/markdown.rb`, but instead I recieve:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       uninitialized constant PostsHelper::Utils
```

I understand that the problem lies in referencing Utils from helper module, but I have zero ideas how to properly make that reference.

Please, help me before my head crashes! =-)

Comment: You can remove the [tag:autoload] and [tag:ruby-on-rails] tags from this question, it's not really related to either. Your problem is just plain ruby **constant lookup**. (Though, of course without autoloading you'd have to use `require`)

Comment: According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html, Ruby constant lookup and Rails autoloading are quite different, so I'd prefer them to stay. =-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I sorta figured it out.

The app/some_name path is "chewed" from module/class finding, so Rails do not expect to find in app/some_name/some_class.rb `SomeName::SomeClass`, it simply expect to find `SomeClass`.

I restructured the file ierarchy, so now it is: app/modules/utils/my_markdown.rb, and it correctly autoloads `Utils::MyMarkdown` from my_markdown.rb =-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
module PostsHelper  
  def markdown_render(data)
    ::Utils::Markdown.render data
  end
end
```

that is, put a double-colon in front of `Utils::Markdown`. It basically means "look in the root namespace," rather than "look within the namespace I'm currently in".

Comment: Nope. `::Utils::Markdown.render data` => `ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant Utils`.

Comment: "I understand that the problem lies in referencing Utils from helper module" - turns out that's not the problem. I've just checked, if you put all the code from both files into /app/helpers/posts_helper.rb, it works. So, the problem is that Rails isn't auto-loading it properly. Not sure why though, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In `markdown.rb`, just define `Markdown` as a top level class (i.e. not in any namespaces).

Comment: Rails should automatically autoload: "All subdirectories of app in the application and engines. For example, app/controllers. They do not need to be the default ones, any custom directories like app/workers belong automatically to autoload_paths." (from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths)

Comment: @joshua.paling Thanks for your comment. Updated my answer.

Comment: It works, thanks. But I do not want to pollute global namespace with such utility classes and methods, I want to keep it tidy. Is there a way to implement such use case?